# how to evaluate joint importance of two features in a model (random forest) using R package such as VIP or DALEXtra?

Tags: r, predictive-models, random-forest, explanatory-models

I know how to use these packages (VIP etc) with `tidymodels` to evaluate individual feature contribution/importance for a model such as random forest. But I'd like to know how to evaluate a combined or joint importance for two or more features. Probably I cannot just simply add importance scores of these features together. Can I ?

for example, we have x1, x2, ... xP features to classify s1, s2, s3, sN samples to two groups (Good or Bad). if we use random forest, we may eventually have ranked importance score for these features to indicate their contribution to classify samples into two groups. we my have features ranking as: x5, x3, x1, x2, .... which indicates x5 have the highest contribution for the model/classification.
My questions if we want to know the joint contribution such as x5+x1, how should we do it? R package VIP permits evaluation for single feature importance but I'd like to know how to calculate joint contribution.

Thank you.

-Xiaokuan